# Highcart data not shown from MySQL to JSON data

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `demo_viewer` WHERE 1 ";

$viewer = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

$view = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($viewer)){

    $view[] = $row;
}

$viewer = json_encode($view,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

why this is code no showing data...
db connection ok,but if the code like below this data showing..

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(numberofview) as count FROM demo_viewer 

        GROUP BY YEAR(created_at) ORDER BY created_at";

$viewer = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

$viewer = mysqli_fetch_all($viewer,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$viewer = json_encode(array_column($viewer, 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: echo `$sql ` and try run it in mysql directly and debug it.

Comment: Naga echo $sql no problem data show in mysql

Comment: then check your DB connection and `$mysqli` object scope.

Comment: check revesion Naga, seccond code show data...but first code no show data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,'SET NAMES utf8mb4');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `demo_viewer` WHERE 1 ";

$viewer = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

$view = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($viewer,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $view[] = $row;
}

$viewer = json_encode($view, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

**EDIT**

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,'SET NAMES utf8mb4');

$sql = "SELECT numberofclick FROM `demo_viewer` GROUP BY YEAR(created_at) ORDER BY created_at ";

$viewer = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

$view = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($viewer,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $view[] = $row['numberofclick'];
}

$viewer = json_encode($view, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

PS: you you should not use select * from table. Because Highchart needs one column value. not all the columns.

Comment: Add `JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR|JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` options in the json_encode...

Comment: I have tested various scenario and found one more option that set mysql char set UTF-8 or upper(updated the answer with it). First echo the `$viewer` json string then debug the chart secondary.

Comment: did you mean collation to utf-8..?database not used any collation (none).

Comment: i have code from here http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/simple-highcharts-chart-example-using-php-mysql-databaseexample.html

Comment: Check my updated answer. If I am not mistaken you are trying to send 3 columns to highchart which is wrong approach...

Comment: check your query(echo and debug in mysql directly).

Comment: Then something you mess up with highchart and mysql data.

Comment: if have a miss up highchart and mysql..why the second code on top can show data to highchart with sum(numberofclick) etc...